# Processing code is slow when using group by in laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am processing in laravel, with `product` table has `300,000 items`. In that table there are many duplicate names, so I used groupBy. But it takes a long time to process. Once I load the page and wait for it to finish processing the data, it also takes about 6 seconds to 7 seconds. Is there any way to optimize it fast,Thanks

```
$listProduct = Product::all()->groupBy('name'); // It takes about 6 seconds to 7 seconds to process this
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve in the end? To list all products or to query it or?

Comment: You can't. dont query all the products at once. if you are showing them in a table use server side (database side) pagination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call the groupBy function in this order, you are referring to a Collection object that tries to group all the models it has received. Models are relatively large objects so it takes a lot of time. A better solution would be to group on the side of the database, which performs such variations much more efficiently.

```php
Product::all()->groupBy('name'); // slow group by on collection returned by all() method

Product::groupBy('name')->get(); // fast group by on database side
```

Comment: I tried your way. But it says error: `SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'product.id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause`

Comment: When grouping by you can select only aggregated values. E.g your products may have price. When you grouping all duplicates in one row you need to determinate what to do with aggregated data which you one to select. You may use  functions like MIN, MAX, COUNT etc.  `Product::selectRaw('max(price), name')->groupBy('name')->get()`